# FadeIn 1 element

Tags: jquery, hover, this, fadein

I'm working on a homepage with 3 portfolio items where when I hover one of them there must fades in a div over this element. But my code fades in all the divs when I hover 1. So I tried it with .closest() but now there is nothing happening. Can someone help me with this?

My html:

```
<div class="hpi">

    <div class="hpi_wrap">
       <h2>Title of this item</h2>
       <p>Blablablab</p>
    </div>

    <img src="//">

<div><!--End hpi1-->

<div class="hpi1">

    <div class="hpi_wrap">
       <h2>Title of this item</h2>
       <p>Blablablab</p>
    </div>

    <img src="//">

<div><!--End hpi2-->

<div class="hpi">

    <div class="hpi_wrap">
       <h2>Title of this item</h2>
       <p>Blablablab</p>
    </div>

    <img src="//">

<div><!--End hpi3-->
```

My .hp1_wrap is styled with display: none;

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {


    $(".hpi").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest('.hpi_wrap').fadeToggle(300);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find()` instead of `closest()`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".hpi").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.hpi_wrap').fadeToggle(300);
    });

});
```